# listitemclick is not called for listview having spinner

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` in  which each row contain an `ImageView`, a `TextView` and a `Spinner`.

*OnItemClickListener* work perfectly for `ImageView` and `TextView` but when I add a `Spinner`, *OnItemClickListener* does not work.

I've used `android:focusable="false"` property for the `Spinner` element and also  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` porperty for the parent `ListView` but that didn't fix it.

Anyone know how to get the *OnItemClickListener* to work with the `Spinner`?

My code for Spinner and ListView is here:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/BBQ_linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="896dp"
    android:layout_height="609dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LinearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textColor="@color/Black">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/BBQ_list"
        android:layout_width="896dp"
        android:layout_height="609dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:visibility="visible"
         >

    </ListView>     
</LinearLayout >
```

and Spinner code is:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerquant"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:entries="@array/quantity_arrays"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:prompt="@string/quantity_prompt" />
```

Comment: Use spinner.setOnClickListener(){...}

Comment: Is the issue that clicking the `Spinner` does nothing, or does the `Spinner` actually expand but when you click the items within the `Spinner`, they do nothing?

Comment: spinner is working but when i click on Listitem nothing happen infact OnItemClickListener is not being called

Comment: can you give any link for example of ListView containing spinner on each row?????